# PHP Displaying Special Chracters

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to output the text from xml through an html file.Xml file is in UTF-8 format.I saved the string after converting by `htmlentities($subcat->Name,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`.String saved as `&pound;1.89 - &pound;3.99 per M&sup2;` in xml.

While displaying i used `htmlentities_decode($cat->Name,ENT_QUOTES)`.But i am getting this error

> Entity 'Acirc' not defined.
>   Entity 'pound' not defined

I wonder what went wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `htmlentities()` in the first place - most HTML entities are not supported in XML.

Use the actual character data instead.

To avoid `<` and `>` in the data breaking the XML,  wrap the data in [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) blocks.

Example:

```
<product>
 <price>
  <![CDATA[£1.89 - £3.99 per m2]]>
 </price>
</product>
```

Comment: Could you give any example to use CDATA.

Comment: @blakcaps I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `html_entity_decode` http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

There is no such function as `htmlentities_decode`

Answer (score 0):

If you use UTF-8 as source and then output it in html remember to set the correct headers and meta like this:

```
 <?php
 header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
```

otherwise you have problems in displaying.

No need to decode/encode anything as Pekka suggested you should not encode them in the first place but use a CData block. T
hen if you set your header and meta correctly you just output them. Saves you a lot of work.

In case your source is encode, just output it to the browser as is